# Why top level domain name is compulsory?

Tags: domain, domain-name

Why is it necessary to have the .com or .org at the end of domain name? what if I want a domain like `http://tkomble` which is better than http://tkomble.com or http://tkomble.org since tkomble is my name and i am neither a organisation nor a commercial entity. Couldn't they have made it such that you can register even without a top level domain name?

There are already some sites like these where they don't want top level domain name like URL shortener sites etc. so they do something like ti.me (Time inc.) or goo.gl. If they could just do a `http://time` wouldn't that be better?

Comment: You can always just [apply for a new gTLD](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) of '.tkomble' and not worry about being under .com, .net, etc.

Comment: @jscott I forgot about that. I haven't heard much since Canon announced interest in 2010 ( http://www.canon.com/news/2010/mar16e.html ). Have any been launched yet? Still, every old regex URL/email verification and every unpolished email program will make them hard to use for a long time yet.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I believe Amazon actually has paid the fees to try and get the most new TLDs registered, but so far none have been official approved, still in approval.  EDIT: http://www.forbes.com/sites/chrisbarth/2012/06/13/amazon-just-spent-millions-applying-for-domain-names-why/

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it necessary to have the .com or .org at the end of domain name?

Because in 1984 the people building the early internet suggested and agreed that's how it would work. Today, if you don't do that, you aren't using the world's DNS system, you are using your own different, non-standard version that nobody else understands or can use (or wants to use).

As to why that was suggested:

> The purpose and expected use of domains is to divide the name management required of a central administration and assign it to sub-administrations.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc920 Jon Postel, October 1984

> since tkomble is my name and i am neither a organisation nor a commercial entity.

That's why the .name TLD was introducted in 2001

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name

> Couldn't they have made it such that you can register even without a top level domain name?

Yes, they could have. Not without trading other benfits away though.

> If they could just do a `http://time` wouldn't that be better?

One company would get `http://time` and the next would have to go for http://time.me anyway. What if someone else got `http://tkomble` before you - then what?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a hierarchical system with delegated responsibilities. A different registry is resposible for each top level domain and these can again delegate responibility for subdomains. If names would be registered without a top level domain, they all would have to be in the single responsibility of the root domain.

Responsible in this case means: handling registering a name including billing, serving information about a name, handling changes in the information like an IP address, etc.